# WordPress custom query pagination with datepicker problem

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, pagination, jquery-ui-datepicker, search-form

I have a search form with 3 fields one of them is JQuery UI datepicker 
and a custom wp_Query to display the search results 
and wordpress pagination function
the search results are displayed correctly
however when I try to go to the next page I think it also displays the results 
correctly but the url doesn't look right
the url looks like this:

```
​/page/2/?search=run&date#038;date
```

and the following error in the console:

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #038;date
at Function.fa.error (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at fa.tokenize (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at fa.select (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.fa (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at n.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
at a.fn.init.n.fn.init (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at new a.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
at n (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

When I remove the date field from the form it works just fine.

this is the JQuery part related to the date

```
    jQuery(function() {
jQuery( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat:'m-yy',
  onClose: function(dateText, inst){
    jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth,1));
    var selected_month = inst.selectedMonth+1;
    var month = jQuery("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = jQuery("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    var full_date = jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
    var myElement = document.getElementById("datepicker");
    console.log(myElement);
    }
  });
});
```

Any idea how can I remove the "#038;date" part from the url ?

I want when the user goes to the second page of the search results for the url to look like this
/page/2/?search=run&date

instead of this
/page/2/?search=run&date#038;date

> It appears that this problem is not related to the datepicker
>   I still don't know why and how to fix it but this question is not describing the problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am sharing about syntax for How to remove "#038;date" part from the url

```
alert(url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?')));
```

Also, Here is a basic workaround for you:

```html
//the URL ( decode it just for GOOD practice)
var someRandomUrl = decodeURI("http://example.com?modal=name");

//here we do the splitting
var splittedParts = someRandomUrl.split("?");

// the first part of the array will be URL you will require
var theURL = splittedParts[0];

// the second part of the array will be the Query String
var theQuery = splittedParts[1];
alert(theURL);
```

I hope that this is useful for you.

Comment: I don't want to remove the whole query string want I want is : 
when the user goes to the second page of the search results for the url to look like this::::
/page/2/?search=run&date
      instead of this::::
/page/2/?search=run&date#038;date